# Accessing String from NSIndex

Tags: iphone

I currently have a UITableView that is populated by a .plist full of exercises. What I want to be able to do is access individual exercises within the table by storing each exercise that is clicked on into an array, that will later be used to populate a seperate UITableView.

How exactly do I get access to these individual cells so that I can store them into this array. Here is what I have so far:

```
-(IBAction) saveWorkout {
    NSMutableArray *workout = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:10];

    [workout addObject: ] // I'm assuming this is where I add a cell to an array (or atleast the cell's string).

}
```

Any help?

Comment: This isn't a direct answer to you question, and please don't take this as harsh criticism, but I strongly suggest reading up on MCV design patterns. Apple has some guides on the developer site. Once you understand MVC you'll see that you are approaching the problem from the wrong direction. The model should be driving the tableview, not the other way around.

Comment: We are here to **help** you solve your problems, not to solve them ourselves (most of us charge good money for that ;)).

Answer (score 0):

Without delving too much into the actual code part of your question, calling `-cellForRowAtIndexPath` to retrieve a title is (can be) extremely expensive, especially if it is called multiple times.  Use `-didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` to get the index of the title within your datasource array, then add that object to your list.  Call `-saveWorkout` when you are finished/reach a certain limit.

A same might look like:

```
-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {
     //other code and such... 
     //get the index of the object in our original array and add the corresponding object to the new array.
     [customWorkoutArray addObject:[workoutArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To restate @CodaFi in code:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *selectedElements;
@synthesize selectedElements=_selectedElements;

- (NSMutableArray *)selectedElements {
    if (!_selectedElements) {
        _selectedElements = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return _selectedElements;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    id element = [self.myModel objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    // this is the key:  this array will now be the basis for your subsequent table of selected items
    [self.selectedElements addObject:element];

    // do something to your model here that indicates it's been selected
    // have your cellForRow... method interrogate this key and draw something special
    [element setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1] forKey:@"selected"];

    // reload that row so it will look different
    [tableView beginUpdates];
    [tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [tableView endUpdates];

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

-(void)didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath {

You can get the index here by indexPath.row

}